# SSL not valid in IE8

Tags: appharbor

My cert seems to be invalid when using IE8/XP. I understand this is because AppHarbor uses SNI, which isn't supported by XP. My question is if there's a solution for this other than rejecting these users.

Comment: Is your date and time set correctly ?

Comment: Also is it only the AppHarbor site that isnt working ?

Comment: @TaylorGibb date and time set correctly on the client machine you mean? i suppose so, but not sure. getting rejects from users.

Comment: @TaylorGibb yes, only the appharbor site isn't working, and only on XP/IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can purchase IP-based SSL for $100/month, see the AppHarbor [SSL and Certificate KB article](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/ssl-and-certificates).

Comment: Yes, I actually emailed them yesterday asking for this after realising that's the only solution.